# Error on array using math notation

Tags: math-mode, arrays

I don't know why this equation have the errors. Thanks if you can help me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\left[h(t)-\lambda t\right]_k=h_{k}-\frac{\lambda}{2 \pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{i\theta(1-k)}d\theta= \left\{\begin{array}{lcm}
h_{k}-\lambda &   if  & k=1 \\
\\ h_{k}      &   if  & k \neq  1 \\
\end{array}  \right. \\
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What `m` in array arguments is supposed to mean? If you change with `c` or `l` it compiles fine

Comment: As koleygr said. Also ``h_{k}-\lambda &   if  & k=1 \\
\\`` you've got two ``\\``s there which is probably not what you want?

Answer (score 5):

The column type `m` is wrong. Besides you have a trailing `\\` that doesn't belong there.

However, you should use `cases`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
[h(t)-\lambda t]_k
= h_{k}-\frac{\lambda}{2 \pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{i\theta(1-k)}\,d\theta
= \begin{cases}
  h_{k}-\lambda & \text{if $k=1$} \\[2ex]
  h_{k}         & \text{if $k \neq  1$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Note that I removed the wrong `\left` and `\right`; I added `\,` in front of the differential symbol.

[image]

Comment: +1. Mathematical typographical detail question: Would you recommend to use an upright d in d\Theta in order to show, that it is an operator?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner That's a recurring question. I'd not use an upright d even under threat, because here it is *not* an operator. Other people are happy to follow a different convention.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was interested in your point of view.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner You may find answers of mine where the dreaded upright d is used, but just to respect the questioner's preference. Let's hope, at least, that the Wolfram originated symbol is left where it belongs (the trashcan, I mean).